# Where does ASP.NET MVC 4 stores accounts information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have installed MVC 4 and created a new "Internet Application". After running the application and adding some accounts I can't find where the information are stored. I have worked with MVC 2 previousely. It stores accounts in an ASP.NET database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the default settings, it is most likely storing the data in an express instance. In Solution Explorer, view hidden files and you should see it. Otherwise, Use SQL Server to check the database it is connecting to in the connection string.

Comment: It's stored as an external SQL Server db.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not shown in Solution Explorer.**

A brand new MVC4 app creates tables user data in the database that your default connection string points to. So if a new MVC 4 app is created with the connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=aspnetdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And then you click on "register" in the new app, the result is that the following tables are created and an entry appears in the webpages_Membership table as this screen shot shows:

[image: MVC 4 created user tables]