# Can not find which database is used for MVC 4 with Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am trying to learn MVC 4 using C# and Entity Framework code first. I have created my model, create my database and populated it with the seed data. I have a ContextInitializer class which is going to drop and create the database each time I test. When I ran it, I can see my data populated on my site, I can edit, create and delete it. But I do not really know where it is stored.

I have looked at the webconfig file and saw the connectionString as follow:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CCConsolidation-20140610143008;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CCConsolidation-20140610143008.mdf"
```

I logged in my localdb and do not see that database at all. No error whatsoever. I tried to change the connectionstring and pointed it to my database on windows azure and still can not see the database anywhere. I do not see the mdf file in my App_Data folder either.

So my questions are 2 folds:

1) Where is my database hiding?

2) How do I deploy it to Windows Azure when time comes to do that? Will it be as easy as changing the connectionstring? I have tried that without success.

Please help!

NB: I have seen a few "similar" questions on this site but the answer pointed me to look at the webconfig which I did. I have traced to my local database but it is still nowhere to be found.

The question I was referring to is [Where does ASP.NET MVC 4 stores accounts information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421277/where-does-asp-net-mvc-4-stores-accounts-information)

Have I missed something?

---

Updated my connection string for Windows Azure:

```
"Data Source=xxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=CCConsolidation;Integrated Security=False;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxxx@yyyy;Password=xxxxxx;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;AttachDBFilename=aspnet-CCConsolidation.mdf"
```

Have anyone seen any issue with this connection string? I used this in the Webconfig to replace SQL express, but the database  was not created.

Comment: Try doing a search for the text at the end of `AttachDBFilename`?  I'm not really sure other than that but that's something I would try

Comment: it's aspnet-CCConsolidation-20140610143008;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDB is a new functionality in SQL Server 2012. It's a simple command line executable (not a service) that can start and stop DB instances on demand. This has nothing to do with the `App_Data` of your application, and the old `AttachFile`.

You can start, stop, delete or create instances using the command line, for example:

```
SqlLocalDb create "MyInstance"
SqlLocalDb start "MyInstance"
SqlLocalDb info "MyInstance"
SqlLocalDb stop "MyInstance"
SqlLocalDb delete "MyInstance"
```

If you want to connect to your DB from SSMS, you need to specify the following DB:

```
(localdb)\MyInstance
```

The advantage of this DB is that you don't need to install a whole SQL Server instance, start and stop services, create logins, grant permissions, and so on.

The [database files are inside your Windows user profile folder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx), and the process is run under your own credentials, so you don't need to give permissions to any folder either.

You can get plenty of info on LocalDB here: [Getting Started with SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/)

Comment: Wonderful! That solves my first puzzle. Regarding the second part of my question, if I do not want to use SQL Express, is it just as simple as changing the connection string? I have tried but it did not work. I changed the connection string to use Windows Azure SQL Server (please see my update regarding the connection string for SQL windows azure) but I did not see the database created. I can connect to Azure using my VS 2012 from the desktop which means there is no problem with the connection string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not living on a local instance of SQL Server (e.g. localhost) but appears to be a SQL Server Express instance fired up with your application and the database is stored in the aspnet-CCConsolidation-20140610143008.mdf in the App_Data directory of your site.

You should be able to browse that datastore from within Visual Studio by double-clicking on the mdf file in your Solution Explorer

Comment: Thanks for the response. My App_Data is empty which confused me. Can I view the instance of SQL Server Express using VS management studio? I have SQL Server 2012, if I change the connection string pointing to that instance, will it create db in there? So far, my attempt was not successful. I might have missed something.